# Retrieve data from data folder postgresql 8.0 version

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have installed PostgreSQL-8.0 version and now the PostgreSQL was corrupted.
I was unable to access the databases which are available in PostgreSQL.
I have data directory which is located in `/Program Files/PostgreSQL/8.0/data`.
I reinstalled PostgreSQL8.0, now help me to retrieve data from this directory.

Comment: (1) If you have a backup, just use that. (2) If not, make sure you take a backup of.../data/ immediately. (3) Try to start postgresql and show the errors in the logs and also the EXACT version number of PostgreSQL (8.0.x). (4) Consider hiring a consultant depending on how important your data is. (5) Version 8.0 was marked end-of-live back in 2010 - general support hasn't been available for 5 years now. Plan for an immediate upgrade should you rescue your data.

Comment: Really, 8.0? The most recent patch to 8.0 was released in 2010, and 8.0.0 was released in 2005. Anyway, Richard is right - before doing *anything* else, copy the entire data directory and all its contents (including `pg_xlog` etc) to a backup location.

Comment: (1)I didn't have backup (2) I have /data/ folder(3) I reinstall the postgreSQL and start services and replace the old /data/ folder in new /data/ place then also i was unable to access the data it's giving the error like..... Could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "127.0.0" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?